# Why is application deployed on Amazon Elastic Beanstalk not accessible?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have deployed Spring MVC & MySQL based application on [Amazon Elastic Beanstalk](http://aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/). The RDS instance of MySQL is working perfectly. I deployed my application war on Beanstalk using Tomcat 6 (which is referring to RDS instance) and the EC2 instance is running successfully as per the AWS Management Console intimation but while accessing application URL I am facing the following issue

```
Error 324 (net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE): The server closed the connection without sending any data.
```

Note: Availing free services of AWS. I have defined instance type as small for RDS and medium for web application and do have S3 instance with 36mb data.

Could any one suggest me what would be the problem?

Answer (score 1):

I resolved the issue by creating EC2 security Groups to the DB instance.